# Electron partially opaque window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, window

I'm wondering if there is a way in electron to have such a view like the finder in macOs where the sidebar is opaque and the main content not:

[image]

I know how to make a whole window opaque but I think there is no way to do it for "just a region", right?

Comment: You can create a transparent window and make part of it opaque with a HTML `<div>` though like @lost.design said you can't blur anything below the transparent part of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you shared is not possible with electron just yet. You can make a transparent window but you cannot add any blur effects to it to get a similar look.